# Can you create an intent filter based on query?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would like to have my application respond to the market link for my application. So the link is market://details?id=my.package.name. Now the reason I want this is so I can send out a link that will open the app if it is installed and open the market page if the application is not installed. The problem I am running into is that my application will respond to all market links and not just my applications link. The reason is the package name is defined in the query part of the Uri. Is there a way to filter an intent based on the query part of the Uri?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, sorry, you cannot. You can constrain a filter based on everything to the left of the `?`, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It explains why I couldn't get this to work. It's not called out real clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 8):

From Android API 19, you can do it, using [`ssp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#ssp), [`sspPrefix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sspPrefix) or [`sspPattern`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sspPattern). Example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:sspPrefix="//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.test"
    />
</intent-filter>
```

With such filter, the OS will offer your app only for URLs with `id=com.example.test` parameter, and won't offer it when there is no such parameter. But this works only on Android 4.4+, older versions will ignore `sspPrefix`.

See also this article: https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-ssp-data-intent-filter/.

Comment: This method is unreliable, even on devices running Android 4.4+, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708662/android-sspprefix-is-ignored