# How do you catch URLs using intent-filter with a specific parameter value

Tags: android

I am trying to use an intent-filter to intercept URLs on QR codes in the format:
https://qx.process.com?f=anyValue
That is, I only want to intercept it if the specified URL as the 'f=' parameter specified.
I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:scheme="https"  android:host="qx.process.com" 
               android:pathPrefix="\\?f=*">
    </data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you create an intent filter based on query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417967/can-you-create-an-intent-filter-based-on-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path concern only the path and not the queryString like your `?XXXX`

Comment: Merci, ChristopheCVB! That's what I thought might be the problem, but I didn't see it specifically called out in any doc.

Comment: Intents Filters are explained here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html