# Android sspPrefix is ignored

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to write an intent-filter so that when my app isn't installed, the user gets linked to the Play Store, otherwise my app is opened. Preferably with some custom data, but this isn't essential. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083294/158703) which seems to provide exactly what I want. However, it doesn't work for me. The Play Store is always opened instead. If I add a host attribute, then my app is always opened, regardless of the actual id provided. So it appears that the sspPrefix attribute is being ignored in all cases. Is there any reason why this might be the case? Am I missing something obvious? I'm using targetSdkVersion 23 and minSdkVersion 17.

More generally, is there a better way to either open the Play Store at an App's page, or that App if it's already installed?

Comment: Note that `sspPrefix` is largely undocumented, and so some devices may not support it, even if the device runs Android 4.4+.

Comment: Good to know. In this case, falling back to simply opening the Play Store is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sspPrefix was added in API 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sspPrefix). IF you're trying to use a version of Android that's < 19, it will not work. Because XMl works the way it does, it simply ignores tags that are added later (they have no meaning on API levels where it isn't added).

Meaning, you're most likely using an API that is < 19, so when you try to access the app it opens google play because the API doesn't know how to handle the tag.

Comment: I've compiled the app using minSdk,targetSdk and compileSdk=25 and I run it on a phone running platform v25 and I still see the same issue. Is it possible my phone is still ignoring it?

Comment: As commonsware mentioned, there are some devices that may not support it (because of custom ROM's either as a result of root or a manufacturer OS). SOme versions may have removed it completely, so there is a chance your phone ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be worth posting how I solved this issue. I created an intent filter for the URL of the download page on my App's website. Thus, if they open it on Android, and they have my App installed, it starts the App. Otherwise the user is led to the download page where they see links to the Play Store. This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it's close enough for me.